# Bootstrap card sizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I'm new to front end web stuff (also back end lol) and was trying to make a dashboard for a discord bot for practice. I am using bootstrap but I am having trouble with the sizing of cards.

I have these cards that I wanted to put inside a container but the cards just leak out on small screens.

eta: Bootstrap 5

```
<div class="container-fluid mx-auto mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color: #212529; padding: 40px; border: 3px solid #f5f5f5; border-radius: 10px; max-height: auto;">

    <!-- cards -->

    <div class="row mx-auto justify-content-center">
        {% for guild in guilds %}
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-4" style="min-width: 150px; min-height: auto;">
            <a href="{{ url_for('guild', guild_id=guild['id']) }}" class="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <div class="card" style="background-color: #ffffff; border: 2px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 7px;">
                    {% if guild['icon'] %}
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid mb-3" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/{{ guild['id'] }}/{{ guild['icon'] }}">
                    {% else %}
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid mb-3" src="../static/defualt_pic_discord.png">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="card-block high">
                        <h1>
                            <div class="display-2 text-center" style="font-size: 1rem; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: #333;"> {{ guild['name']}} </div>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been at this for a while and am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome! _the cards just leak out on small screens._ What does that mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.